# excel con 4 columnas en python

Tags: python, excel, outlook

soy principiante en python, y estoy tratando de leer mi correo de outlook, tengo una misión en mi trabajo que es dejar en un excel el asunto, cuerpo, cantidad de adjuntos y fecha de recibido de cada mensaje cuyo asunto contenga la palabra "solicitud". Sin embargo, tengo un inconveniente que ni siquiera sé como buscar (ya que cómo digo soy principiante). Agradecería a quien pueda ayudarme!!

EL problema es que requiero un excel con las 4 columnas que menciono, pero estoy teniendo como resultado algo así:

```
'                                                 0
0                          Solicitud Revisión RB1872

1  Buena Noche Nivelso Tu colaboración con la rev...

2                                                  1

3                                20/05/2021 22:13 PM

                                                   0
0         RE: Cargabilidad en MVA (Solicitud ticket)

1  ORDEN DE SERVICIO ASIGNADAOSATR2856-2021Respon...

2                                                  1

3                                21/05/2021 15:21 PM

                                                   0
0  Solicitud paridad RB1249 y RB1256 Cto 7 SE Pailon

1  Buenas tardes, Favor validar la paridad de RB12...

2                                                  1

3                                21/05/2021 15:50 PM'
```

requiero que queden como columnas, además que se cree una lista, pues incluso cuando he logrado tenerlo como muchas filas con las 4 columnas (cómo muestro a continuación), solo logro que se imprima en el Excel el primer registro.

```
('Solicitud Revisión RB1872', 'Buena Noche Nivelso Tu colaboración con la revisión en campo del Reconectador en asunto, 1, '20/05/2021 22:13 PM')

('RE: Cargabilidad en MVA (Solicitud ticket)', 'ORDEN DE SERVICIO , 1, '21/05/2021 15:21 PM')

('Solicitud paridad RB1249 y RB1256 Cto 7 SE Pailon', 'Buenas tardes, 2, '21/05/2021 15:21 PM')
```

Este es el código que tengo al momento:

```
import win32com.client
import os
import pandas as pd
import csv
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

#Llamando a la función GetNamespace, puedes obtener la sesión de la perspectiva para las operaciones posteriores.
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders("Gestión de Aplicaciones Operación").Folders("Bandeja de entrada") 
messages = inbox.Items

##Utilice la función Restrict para filtrar su mensaje de correo electrónico.

received_dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=500)
received_dt = received_dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + received_dt + "'")
messages = messages.Restrict("@SQL=(urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%Solicitud%')")

outputDir = r"C:\Users\mfhernandezp\Documents\CORREO"
for message in list(messages):
    
    ##METODO1
    df=message.subject
    df1=message.body.replace('\n',"").replace('\r',"").replace('\t',"").replace('\v',"").replace('\a',"").replace('\b',"").replace('\f',"").replace('\0',"").replace('\\',"").replace('\'',"").replace('\"',"").replace(';',"").replace('<',"").replace('<<',"").replace('>',"").replace('>>',"")
    df2=message.Attachments.Count
    df3=message.CreationTime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p')
    df4=(df,df1,df2,df3)
    df5=pd.DataFrame(df4)
    print(df5)
```

Agradezco enormemente si alguien puede darme una luz de cómo proseguir

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, has creado una muy buena primera pregunta, con un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Aún así, permíteme recomendarte que hagas el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que ganes tu primer medalla y te familiarices con las normas de la comunidad. Saludos!

Comment: Lo único que te recomiendo es cambiar el título por algo más significativo que se relacione con la pregunta

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Una forma muy fácil para lograr lo que buscas es utilizar un diccionario para crear el `dataframe`, de esa forma le das la estructura que necesitas.

```
#Creamos diccionario vacío
d = {}
#Iteramos en los mensajes y obtenemos el índice y el mensaje
for i, message in enumerate(messages):
    #Llenamos el diccionario en el índice correspondiente
    d[i] = {'subject': message.subject,
            'body': message.body.replace('\n',"").replace('\r',"").replace('\t',"").replace('\v',"").replace('\a',"").replace('\b',"").replace('\f',"").replace('\0',"").replace('\\',"").replace('\'',"").replace('\"',"").replace(';',"").replace('<',"").replace('<<',"").replace('>',"").replace('>>',""),
            'attachments': message.Attachments.Count,
            'date': message.CreationTime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p')}
```

Para poder convertir el diccionario a `dataframe` utilizamos [`pandas.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) y para que las llaves del diccionario sean los índices del `dataframe` utilizamos el argumento `orient='index'`

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=d, orient='index')
```

Esto devuelve un `dataframe` con la siguiente forma (Tuve que ocultar lo que decía mi correo y sustituirlo por valores genéricos subject y body):

```
    subject     body    attachments date
0   subject1    body1   0           17/05/2022 16:14 PM
1   subject2    body2   0           20/05/2022 12:52 PM
2   subject3    body3   0           20/05/2022 14:39 PM
3   subject4    body4   0           20/05/2022 14:41 PM
4   subject5    body5   0           20/05/2022 15:04 PM
5   subject6    body6   0           20/05/2022 15:18 PM
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import win32com.client
import os
import pandas as pd
import csv
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

carpetaExterna = 'Gestión de Aplicaciones Operación'
carpetaInterna = 'Bandeja de entrada'

#Llamando a la función GetNamespace, puedes obtener la sesión de la perspectiva para las operaciones posteriores.
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders(carpetaExterna).Folders(carpetaInterna)
messages = inbox.Items

received_dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=500)
received_dt = received_dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + received_dt + "'")
messages = messages.Restrict("@SQL=(urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%solicitud%')")

d = {}
for i, message in enumerate(messages):
    
    d[i] = {'subject': message.subject,
            'body': message.body.replace('\n',"").replace('\r',"").replace('\t',"").replace('\v',"").replace('\a',"").replace('\b',"").replace('\f',"").replace('\0',"").replace('\\',"").replace('\'',"").replace('\"',"").replace(';',"").replace('<',"").replace('<<',"").replace('>',"").replace('>>',""),
            'attachments': message.Attachments.Count,
            'date': message.CreationTime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p')}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=d, orient='index')
print(df)
```